# How can i use UpateView and ListView together?

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-templates

I have a form to update, but this page also has a list of objects to display, and I don't know how to combine functionality of UpdateView and ListView.
I read about mixins but did not understand how to use them with UpdateView

views.py

```
class VacancyEdit(UpdateView):
    model = Vacancy
    template_name = 'vacancies/vacancy-edit.html'
    fields = ['title', 'skills', 'description', 'salary_min', 'salary_max']
    pk_url_kwarg = 'vacancy_id'
    success_url = '/'
    context_object_name = 'Application'
```

Comment: I think you probably need to explain exactly what you're trying to do a bit better. Are you sure you need to combine them? Why not just have a ListView and a separate UpdateView?

Comment: I need to combine functionality of UpdateView and ListView , because i have list of objects and form to update on the same page , and i want to do it with cbv

Answer (score 1):

UpdateView is required lookup field to find single object that you updating and returns that object when get request but list view returns queryset so you can't combine update and list views.